# In the below code what is the meaning of +\ in return countWaysUtil(val, n, num + 1) +\ countWaysUtil(x, n, num + 1) . Please someone tell me

Tags: python

```
def countWaysUtil(x,n,num):
    val = (x - pow(num, n))
    if (val == 0):
        return 1
    if (val < 0):
        return 0

    
    return countWaysUtil(val, n, num + 1) +\
        countWaysUtil(x, n, num + 1)



def countWays(x,n):
    return countWaysUtil(x, n, 1)

    

x = 100
n = 2

print(countWays(x, n))
```

Answer (score 0):

`\` is an escape character in many programming languages. In python case, this tells the interpreter/ compiler to ignore the next line break (`\n`) so it would not be considered as end of statement. then the addition can be continued with the operand in the next line